# How to prevent Mail creating a local Sent Messages folder

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I have a Gmail account in Mail.app that behaves a bit weird: whenever I send an email, Mail tells me that it created a local "Sent Messages" folder and changed my settings.

The sent email messages are correctly saved in the Sent Items on the Gmail server (this is the behavior I want), but they are also saved in this local folder. Is there a way to prevent Mail creating this local folder and save sent messages **only on the server**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select Gmail's `Sent` folder, then go to `Mailbox > Use This Mailbox For > Sent`.